# Processing groups of point-matrix multiplications with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Given two parallel arrays, one an array of rotation matrices, and the other an array of groups of 3D points, I'm looking for the fastest way to multiply each subgroup by the its corresponding matrix.

I was able to achieve what I want by looping over each group with numpy.einsum. I'm hoping there is a way to do this without the loop. This is the code i have so far:

```
import numpy as np
N_GROUPS = 10
N_SUBGROUPS = 4

p = np.random.random((N_SUBGROUPS,N_GROUPS,3,)) # N_GROUPS of N_SUBGROUPS of 3D points
M = np.random.random((N_GROUPS,3,3,))           # N_GROUPS of rotation matrices
I = np.linalg.inv(M)                            # Inverse of M for testing purposes

# Use a loop to transform every subgroup.
for i in xrange(N_SUBGROUPS):
    p_ = np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', p[i], M)

    # test
    p__= np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', p_, I)
    print np.allclose(p[i],p__)# Returns True
```

Any help to rewrite the einsum expression to deal with my situation, or suggestions on how to use another method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a result array of dimension `(N_SUBGROUPS, N_GROUPS, 3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really straightforward: you've done most of the work yourself!

Just take the index corresponding to subgroups and put it on both sides of the einsum equation: that'll give you the desired array of dimension `(N_SUBGROUPS, N_GROUPS, 3)`.

Suppose we call the subgroup index `l`, then:

```
p_ = np.einsum('lij,ijk->lik', p, M)

# I've changed the subgroup range index for clarity
for l in range(N_SUBGROUPS):
    # test
    p__= np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', p_[l], I)
    print(np.allclose(p[l],p__))  # Returns True
```

Comment: I feel so dumb, thank you! I ended up using ellipsis broadcasting so I can handle all the bundling variations i can throw at it: `np.einsum('...ij,ijk->...ik', p, M)`